# How to convert complex data frame values to floats in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, floating-point, complextype

I have a data frame converted from time domain to frequency domain using Fourier transform which resulted in imaginary/complex values. I need to convert the `DataFrame` to floats in order to be able to classify the data.
How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([complex(x,y) for x,y in 
          zip(np.random.randn(3),np.random.randn(3))])
print(df)

Out:
                                  0
0  (0.815555184453+0.942659258939j)
1  (0.725136694628+0.999826686401j)
2  (0.311981899931+0.309615235755j)
```

If you would like the magnitude of the complex numbers, you can take the modulus (r in polar coordinates):

```
df.applymap(np.absolute)

Out:
          0
0  1.246490
1  1.235102
2  0.439539
```

If you would like to lose the imaginary component you can cast to floats:

```
df.astype(np.float64)

Out:
          0
0  0.815555
1  0.725137
2  0.311982
```

Comment: df.applymap(np.absolute) gives an error massege:  KeyError: ("ufunc 'absolute' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U22') dtype('<U22')", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Guessing from your error message you have fields containing strings (of length 22 chars). Please provide sample data of your problem.

Comment: If you just want to cast one column of complex numbers to the reals (magnitude) you can use `df[colname].apply(np.absolute)`

Comment: df.applymap(np.absolute). worked! and converted the whole data frame. Thank you